# How to remove calendar widget?

Tags: widgets

I just want to remove calendar widget  from the dashboard. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to remove a default widget from WordPress. Just add this to your functions.php file:

```
function remove_calendar_widget() {
    unregister_widget('WP_Widget_Calendar');
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'remove_calendar_widget' );
```

See more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget

Comment: Thanks, but It's not working......

Comment: Sorry Nyxko, your code is working.

Thank you so much for your help......

Comment: One more thing Nyxko that is, I am trying to create widget, so please can you guide me that from where I have to start to develop widget..

Comment: The WordPress Widgets API has documentation and examples on how to create custom wigets. Always look into WordPress codex for answers. http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Comment: That does not work anymore. Widget stays available in the backend.